# Alfresco can't access to admin account after computer shut-down

Tags: postgresql, alfresco

So i'm using Alfresco community edition and every time i shut down my computer and  run the postgresql and tomcat i can't login to my admin account.

it says that Your authentication details haven't been recognized or Alfresco Content Services may not be available at this time.

Comment: please share your error logs of tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look into the tomcat logs. There you should see the real problem. Share doesn't expose any error on the login page and says always that your authentication details haven't been recognized even Alfresco (repository) is not up'n running.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Heiko, Alfresco Share does not expose to end users technical details about the backend repo not being available, which can be one of many things, and the logs are the best place to look for further details about the real issue.

This is however, in my experience, most of the time caused by one of these issues:

1- You have a separate tomcat for Alfresco Repo, and that one is not started up

2- You database server is either not up or not available, you might then want to try connecting to it from the alfresco host using a command line tool and the credentials from `alfresco-global.properties`

3- There is a permission issue preventing Alfresco Repo from running correctly (can occur on windows server in a custom install, or in linux when you switch to an other user after the first run ...)

4- Your webapp (either the war or the exploded folder) is corrupt. In which case, you will need to remove that and reset to the OOTB artifacts

5- Share is having some issues communicating with Alfresco Repo! Firewall? IP Tables ? port forwarding ?